# How can I to take a child object from a parent and add it to a list?

Tags: relationships

Sorry that this is such a basic question, but i could not find out how to do this, I do not want to create a query, which is what most of the solutions i find on the internet are.

Example:

```
 **Submittal_Package__c is a child of Project__C (master detail relationship)**

public List<SelectOption> getItems(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Submittal_Package__c> tempSubPackList = new List<Submittal_Package__c>();

    for(Project__c projvar : projectstab){
      tempSubPackList.add(projvar.Submittal_Package__c);
    }
    return (tempSubPackList);
    for(Submittal_Package__c subPack : tempSubPackList){
      options.add(new SelectOption(subPack));
    }
    return (options);
  }
```

I am trying to create a for loop that takes the Submittal package out of the project, adds it to a list and then out puts the list as options into a `Apex:selectList` Tag.
`Submittal_Package__c` is not a field on the `Project__c` - because of this I get "`Invalid foreign key Relationship Project__c.Submittal_Package__c` "- does anyone know the proper syntax for this, or where to look/ key words to google?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Somewhere, before getItems() is invoked, a query has to be done that looks like `[select id, (select id, ... from submittal_packages__r) from project__c where id = :someidOfTheProjectInScope] as the detail records just don't appear in thin air when you are acting on a project__c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First bug in your program logic is that you are returning tempSubPackList before the for loop itslsef and the return type is also different from what you are returning this is throws some error.

Then inorder to achieve your requirement i think you should change the query for projectstab list to relational query and then you can parse the child object.

In your case you want to query Submittal_Package__c  while querying projectstab list.

Your query will look something like this

```
select id , name ( select id , name from Submittal_Package__c) 
from Project__c 
where some_condition.
```

This will get you the child records based on the parent record then you can parse the list in order to get the Submittal_Package__c record and add it to the option and return it.

[Relational query reference link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#i1422263).